# Determining subfields of cyclotomic field extension

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-polynomials

I am trying to determine the number of subfields of $\mathbb Q (\zeta_{16})$ for which $[M :\mathbb Q]=2$ and their structure. (Where $M$ is a subfield and $\zeta_n$ is $n$th primitive root of unity )

It seems to be easier when $n$ is a prime but...

I believe the $Gal(\mathbb Q(\zeta_{16}):\mathbb Q)$ is has order 8 and the structure $(\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z)^* ≅ C_2 \times C_4$, is this correct and could I use these facts to help me find the subfields? Would it have the structure of $C_2$ perhaps?

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: The quadratic subfields are $\mathbb{Q}(i),\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi / 8))=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}), \mathbb{Q}(i\sin(2\pi / 8)) =\mathbb{Q}(i\cos(2\pi / 8)) = \mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{2}) =  \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{-2})$

Comment: By Galois theory, the subfields of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ are in bijection with the subgroups of the Galois group.